# AWK Script throwing syntax error on for loop

Tags: unix, syntax, awk

I'm trying to get this script working to count how many files of type .doc and .pdf are. But I keep getting syntax error on the last bracket for the for loop.

```
awk: ./parselog.awk:14:     for ($7 in count)
awk: ./parselog.awk:14:                     ^ syntax error
```

Here's the awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {}
{
    file = match($7, "/datasheets/")
    doccheck = match(tolower($7), ".doc")
    pdfcheck = match(tolower($7), ".pdf")
    if( doccheck || pdfcheck )
    {
            count[$7]++
    }
}
    END{

    for ($7 in count)
    {
            frequency = count[$7]
            sub(/datasheets/,"",$7)
            minusextension = $7
            sub(/\....$/, "", minusextension)
            print minusextension, $7, frequency
    }
    sort
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `$7` as a variable name in that `for` loop. Change all the `$7` in your `END` block to `key` or something like that.

Comment: Of course you can use `$7` as a variable name.  It's just not a good idea, and the confusion surrounding it is likely to break your code.  Try this: `printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' | awk '1 END { $3="foo"; print $3; }'`

Comment: `awk 'END { a[1] = 0; for ($1 in a) {} }'` => syntax error; `awk 'END { a[1] = 0; for (b in a) {} }'` no syntax error.

Comment: Ah, just in the for loop.  Interesting.  I take back my -1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a one-liner:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ find . \( -name "*.doc" -or -name "*.pdf" \) -print | awk -F. '{c[$NF]++} END {for(ext in c){printf("%5.0f\t%s\n", c[ext], ext);}}'
  232   pdf
   45   doc
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Note that this moves the selection of extensions out of the awk script and into the `find` command earlier in the pipe.  If you really want to make this a stand-alone awk-only script (and not shell), I suppose you could do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {

  # List of extensions we're interested in:
  exts["doc"]=1;
  exts["pdf"]=1;

  FS=".";
  cmd="find . -print";
  while (cmd | getline) {
    if (exts[$NF]==1) {
      c[$NF]++;
    }
  }
  for (ext in c) {
    printf("%5.0f\t%s\n", c[ext], ext);
  }
  exit;
}
```

Note that the `find` command also traverses subdirectories.  If you want only the current directory, you can swap in `ls *.pdf *.doc` and just `ls` respectively.